# Powershell + in a string not valid

Tags: string, powershell, operators

I have to replace a phone number in a document but when there is no phone number from mu user I have to delete this row 
The default document looks like this:

```
company
street
T: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #phone
F: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #Fax
M: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #Mobile
```

When for example a user has no mobile phone I have to delete this row

```
$content = $content -replace "M:",""
$content = $content -replace "+00",""
$content = $content -replace "xxx xxx xxx",""
```

But I'm getting this error

```
The regular expression pattern +39 is not valid.
At line:65 char:1
+ $content = $content -replace "+39",""
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (+39:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

How can I now delete this row when power shell doesn't want my + in a string

Delete the row:

After deleting successful the mobile number document looks like this:

```
company
street
T: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #phone
F: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #Fax

more information
```

But it should look like this

```
company
    street
    T: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #phone
    F: +00 xxx xxx xxx  #Fax
    more information
```

Comment: can you provide an example line where phone number needs to get deleted?

Comment: Can you also show what should be in the end?

Comment: i hope you understand now what i mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex `replace`, but use `String.Replace`:

```
$content = $content.Replace("M:","")
$content = $content.Replace("+00","")
$content = $content.Replace("xxx xxx xxx","")
```

This should work for you:

```
$content = Get-Content $filepath | foreach-object { if (!$_.StartsWith("M:")) { $_ } }
$content
```

Comment: thanks that worked and how can i delete the row no is there space between the next rows

Comment: after the row where the mobile number is are other rows with information's. When I set the row with the mobile number to "" (nothing) there is one row without anything in how can i delete this row that there is no more space between the row Fax and the next row

Comment: Is it possible to get it as a string array instead of 1 string?

Comment: i dont know i'm beginner in powershell i have a rtf document and get the content with : $content = Get-Content $filepath -raw

Comment: see update, but regex option could be a bit better here

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `regex` to filter them:

```
$content | Where { $_ -notmatch '^M: \+00' }
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it!

Comment: @briantist sorry :-p.

Comment: Probably its how you retrieve the `$content` variable (you have to omit the  `-raw` parameter to get an array. However, you already got an comprehensive answer.